# How to add an "or" instead of and "and" (&) in a Wordpress query?

Tags: query-posts, loop

I would like to accomplish something like this:

```
        <?php $custom_posts = new WP_Query(); ?>
        <?php $custom_posts->query('category_name=Business OR category_name=Technology OR category_name= Lifestyle'); ?>
        <?php while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="content-block-14">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

So that if the post belongs to only one of those categories it should be listed in that loop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you try `is_category();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the category ID you can use the [**`category__in`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) parameter eg:

```
<?php $custom_posts->query(array('category__in' =>array(1,2,3))); ?>
```